# How do you create change logs for your projects?

Tags: project-management, bugzilla, change-management

I am using subversion as an RCS and Bugzilla for issue tracking. And i just ask myself how to create automatic change logs for the users?

I already tried the "svn2cl" tool. But the change logs it creates are to technical for me (e.g. no user want's to know that developer XY changed 20 files yesterday to fix a memory leak). A user wants a change log which contains something like this:

> Version 1.0
> - Added feature 1
>
> Version 1.1
> - fixed bug #4711
> - added feature 2
> ...

Does anybody know a tool, addon or script to create change logs from my bugzilla entries? Or is there an good way to do this?
I know trac supports the creation of change logs, but i don't like trac very much.

**Update**
Wrote my own little tool for this job. You can get it at [ChangelogGenerator](http://www.cfgnet.de/project_changeloggen.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sourceforge project called Bugzilla Changelog which generate this log as HTML or Wiki - text.

See: [Bugzilla Changelog Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bugzillachnglog/)

Comment: Looks exactly what i am searching for. But this projects is not documented. Absolutely no clue how this works.

Comment: Usually extensions just need to be un-packed and copied to: BUGZILLA_ROOT/extensions/extension_name
But I'm not a bugzilla admin, perhaps sombody who has more experience with it can explain it better.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect now. I had to modify the script a bit because it didn't support different MySQL sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom tool which logs in a database changes per project, module etc. these changes are then exportable to files using a custom addin for finalbuilder for readme production, or exportable to a webservice which imports them into a local db for the webserver so users can view/search online what's changed per module.

Comment: Yes, writing a custom tool which connects to the database, groups the bugs by their target milestone and status and writes a change log would be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can have Bugzilla generate it for you.
Use the Advanced Bug Search screen, filter on the milestone /  version, on the status and resolution.
Then you can export it as  CSV format and work on it in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Excel? :)

I'm assuming for each version you first create a list of features to implement, changes to make, bugs to fix etc. Somewhere the status of these must be tracked so you know what is complete, what has been pushed to a later version and so on, and when it's time to test and ship.

This information in your tracking document pretty much contains everything you need.

Comment: That the point. My tracking document is Bugzilla! All features and bugs to do for the next version are assigned to specific target milestone. All information i need to create a change log are given. But how can i do this without copying everthing to excel, doing the formatting stuff...